# Click WPF button from another application

Tags: c#, wpf

Was thinking it would be an easy task, but it proved to be far from that.
Spy++ doesn't generate control ID's (Only shows main window), each control has a name. Example(Button->"AddButton")
I've tried using invoked methods such as SendMessage, and i get the main window handle just fine, but always get a 0 when trying to get control handles.

I heard about UI Automation library, but didn't find any clear examples of usage for my specific task.

My Goal:Being able to retrieve data (Such as data grid cells texts), and click buttons on a WPF application, remotely from another application (I'll be using C#)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've tried Ranorex Spy and was able to click the control just fine:
[Press button from Ranorex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PFSU.png)

How can i simulate it?

EDIT 2:
I managed to do it after further reading some documentations, hopefully it will help other people:

```
            string mainTitle = "";
        string controlName = "";

        AutomationElement prog = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, mainTitle));
        AutomationElement btn = prog.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, controlName));
        InvokePattern clickBtn = (InvokePattern) btn.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);

        clickBtn.Invoke();
```

Comment: What application do you want to get the data from?

Comment: Just some WPF application, am i required to give the specific application name?

Comment: Your post doesn't make much sense? Why do you have two wpf applications and why do you want to share data and events between them?

Comment: Why not? and I have one application connected to a server on a host machine, and i want the server to send data to the connected socket, which will then make Click a button on that application, i am not sure why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just edited my post as i managed to solve this particular issue, but will also need a way of extracting data grid elemnts (Cells in particular)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use UI Automation which was (kinda) designed to do this kind of stuff. There is also a NuGet-Package which does some work for you already, called TestStack.White. Originally it is designed for automated UI testing, but I don't see why you couldn't use it for doing stuff like that. You can find out more about the Package [here](http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GettingStarted/), and more about UI Automation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Comment: Will take a look for sure, right now i am trying to figure out how to get a datagrid rows Cells